# Form Open is hiding and disabling the Navigation Pane

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am debugging an access application built by another developer. As I debug, I want to be able to see the results of specific queries and tables as I go. On one particular form, the navigation pane (which includes the list of tables, queries, forms...etc) is minimized and disabled any time the form is open. The navigation then maximizes and is fully restored when the form is closed or in design mode.

I've searched throughout the VBA and there doesn't seem to be anything that's controlling this behavior. I know there is some VBA that can do this like

```
DoCmd.NavigateTo "acNavigationCategoryObjectType"
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide
```

but none of these can be found in the code behind. Any idea what else might be causing this?

Comment: Could it be embedded macros? have a look at the object properties (F4 in Design view) and look at the Event tab.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I checked the events for Form and Detail, and there is an event for Form On Open, but it just loads some data into the form.

Comment: Is that the only event? Can you paste the code here? If you're absolutely stuck in the meantime, you can use F11 to toggle the Access Object List (the navigation pane).. It seems like there's a Macro or a Module/Sub that's handling this event. Maybe with another pair of eyes we will be able to identify it if you share with us what you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Modal` property of the Form will cause such behavior when set to true.

You can set that property on the property sheet for that form in the "Other" tab. It can be set by VBA-Code with code like this:

```
Forms("yourForm").Modal = True '(or False to disable)
```